# Select from a list of values from JSON encoded data

Tags: mysql, performance, query-performance

I have saved the details of the product in JSON format.
I am wondering how to select from a list of values from a "JSON_ENCODED DATA"

For Example
`I want to select TV with screen_type as LED or LCD.`

And the value is saved as

```
{"screen_size":"22 - 24", "screen_type":"LED", "smart_tv":"no", "3d":"no", "resolution":"HD Ready", "hdmi":"1", "usb":"1"}
```

It is possible to do with `UNION` query like:

```
SELECT * FROM `nw_object_detail` WHERE `details` LIKE '%"screen_type":"LED"%'  
UNION  
SELECT * FROM `nw_object_detail` WHERE `details` LIKE '%"screen_type":"LCD"%'
```

But the query will be too lengthy if there are lot of choices. 
Is there are any solution in a simpler way.

Comment: If you need to search on the data, do not store in JSON format. Add proper columns in the table for the attributes that you want to search one (screen_type, screen_size, resolution, etc...)

Comment: but @ypercube I don't have a predefined set of attributes. The attributes are selected dynamically, based on the selected category.

Comment: It won't be easy then and the queries will not be efficient at all. I suggest you look into Postgres with (hstore or JSON).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got a solution:

1. Single check of value in JSON array

   ```
   SELECT * FROM `nw_object_detail` 
   WHERE ((`details` like '%"screen_type":"%LED%"%'))
   ```
2. One value from multiple possibilities

   ```
   SELECT * FROM `nw_object_detail`
   WHERE ((`details` like '%"screen_type":[%"%LCD%"%]%')
   ```

PHP Solution

```
if(count($options)>1): 
    $condition = '(';
    $count = 1;
    foreach( $options as $option ): 
        $condition .= '(`details` like \'%"'.$key.'":[%"%'.$option.'%"%]%\')';
        if(count($options)!=$count): 
            $condition .= ' OR ';
        endif;
    endforeach;
$condition .= ')';
```

Comment: Why did you change the `LIKE '%"screen_type":"LED"%'` to `LIKE '%"screen_type":%"%LED%"%'`? This may result in false positives.

Comment: you are right @ypercube. it points to false positivies. When converting to json, the data with one value are saved in format "key":"value" and the array as "key":["value1","value2"]

Comment: Make sure to safely escape those values to prevent SQL injection!